# Why isn't this awk command working

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

So the question is:

Display all of the lines in the file showing only the quantity and product name, in that order, using awk. Product name is the first field and quantity is the second field. The data file is "inventory"

The contents to inventory:

```
Strawberry Jam,300,4

Raspberry Jam,1216,7

Blueberry Jam,96,195

Strawberry Compote,49,621

Raspberry Compote,1937,624

Blueberry Compote,200,625

Frozen Strawberries,130,1941

Straw Hats,16,2047
```

My command was

```
awk '$2 $1' inventory
```

That should work right? I also tried like

```
awk '{print $2 $1}' inventory
awk '$2, $1' inventory
```

and a lot of variations of that, but none works! Can anyone help figure out why?

Comment: awk '{print $2, $1}' should work or pls paste some example data from your inventory file

Comment: it should right? i tried it mutliple times it doesn't....

Comment: there is a comma between $2 and $1, did you try it? in your question, you missed the comma. pls provide some sample input

Comment: if that isn't working, then what char do you use to separate columns. If it's not whitespace, then you need to specify like `awk -F'|' {...} inventory`. Good luck.

Comment: It works with or without comma

Comment: @Kent I tried everything similar to that none work for some reason...

Comment: *doesn't work* is meaningless.

Comment: what more can I say? The input that im putting in isn't being accepted even thought it should be right

Comment: Considering you haven't provided the contents of `inventory` I'm going with it's a blank file and `awk` is working perfect well, disprove.

Comment: *isn't being accepted* is also meaningless.

Comment: Strawberry Jam,300,4
Raspberry Jam,1216,7
Blueberry Jam,96,195
Strawberry Compote,49,621
Raspberry Compote,1937,624
Blueberry compote,200,625
Frozen Strawberries,130,1941
Straw Hats,16,2047

that is the contents to "inventory"

Comment: I edited my original post to show the inventory contents

Comment: @albert You need to post that in an edit to your question. Comments lose line formatting, which is key here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a `csv` *(comma seperated values)* file so the `field separator` needs to be specified as `,` using the `-F` option.

```
$ awk -F, '{print $2,$1}' inventory

300 Strawberry Jam
1216 Raspberry Jam
96 Blueberry Jam
49 Strawberry Compote
1937 Raspberry Compote
200 Blueberry Compote
130 Frozen Strawberries
16 Straw Hats
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $2, $1}' inventory
```