# How do I use awk to display all lines but with a criteria in the 2nd field?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

So the question is:

Display all of the lines in the file with less than 100 items in inventory, using awk. Quantity is the 2nd field.

I tried

```
 awk '$2 < 100' inventory
```

but that ONLY shows the lines less than 100 in the 2nd field, this is asking me to show all the lines, and i am not sure how to show that, can someone help me out?

---

Strawberry Jam,300,4

Raspberry Jam,1216,7

Blueberry Jam,96,195

Strawberry Compote,49,621

Raspberry Compote,1937,624

Blueberry Compote,200,625

Frozen Strawberries,130,1941

Straw Hats,16,2047

^ inventory file contents

Comment: no it does not do the trick

Comment: Er. How exactly does this not already do what you want?

Comment: "display all the lines with less than 100 items" where number of items are stored in the 2nd field... your code "shows *only* the lines with less than 100 in the 2nd field"... isn't it correct?? you show all the line, or you show all the line with a number less than 100 as 2nd field... what do you mean?

Comment: I am confused by your question, are you asking if any line with quantity < 100, then print entire file?

Comment: Not sure? There are 3 fields, the 2nd field is supposed to display lines with less than 100 in inventory but just having '$2 >= 100' or '$2 < 100' only shows the 2nd field

Comment: I have no idea what you just said.

Comment: @livibetter so it's asking to print ALL lines in the file and in the 2nd field the criteria is to print only if there are less than 100 in that field...is that clear?

Comment: aaahh then  `$2 < 100 {print $0}`

Comment: @albert might be, but you need to edit your question to make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F, '$2<100' file
```

test

```
kent$  cat test
Raspberry Jam,1216,7
Blueberry Jam,96,195
Strawberry Compote,49,621
Raspberry Compote,1937,624
Blueberry Compote,200,625
Frozen Strawberries,130,1941

kent$  awk -F, '$2<100' test
Blueberry Jam,96,195
Strawberry Compote,49,621
```

Comment: ... This is identical to the other answers you got that "didn't work".

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $2 < 100 {print}' inventory
```

**Explanation:**:

- `awk`: invoke the awk command
- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}'`: use `,` as delimiter for both input and output, because I still remember the format for your input file from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573869/why-isnt-this-awk-command-working/)
- `$2 < 100 {print}`: whenever the condition `$2 < 100` is true, print the entire line.
- `inventory`: name of your input file.

**Input:**

```
Strawberry Jam,300,4
Raspberry Jam,1216,7
Blueberry Jam,96,195
Strawberry Compote,49,621
Raspberry Compote,1937,624
Blueberry Compote,200,625
Frozen Strawberries,130,1941
Straw Hats,16,2047
```

**Output:**

```
Blueberry Jam,96,195
Strawberry Compote,49,621
Straw Hats,16,2047
```

Comment: how do you know the field separator is a comma?

Comment: *doesn't work* is still meaningless.

Comment: @ShinTakezou he asked this question just moments ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573869/why-isnt-this-awk-command-working/

Comment: ah ok I was worried about my ability of reading the content of a question! :)

Comment: sorry that doesn't work either, sorry i can't be more helpful...i edited my post and showed the contents of inventory but it's just not working!

Comment: *doesn't work* is still meaningless.

Comment: @albert what is the output? "doesn't work" doesn't give us any more information; help us help you.

Comment: there is no output because this is a specific assignment and there is only a 'pass or fail' like if the code works, then i move on if it doesn't then i have to try again with no information on why it's not working

Comment: @albert you should probably also post the specifications of the question

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print all the lines with `awk` then:

```
awk '{print $0}'
```

---

If you want to print line where-by the second field is less than 100 characters:

```
$ cat inventory

1,2,3
1,12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890,0
```

Like this:

```
`awk -F, '$2 < 100 {print $0}' inventory`

1,2,3
```

If you want to print line the lines base on the value of the second field:

---

```
$ awk -F, '$2<100' file

Blueberry Jam,96,195
Strawberry Compote,49,621
Straw Hats,16,2047

$ awk -F, '$2>100' file

Strawberry Jam,300,4
Raspberry Jam,1216,7
Raspberry Compote,1937,624
Blueberry Compote,200,625
Frozen Strawberries,130,1941
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. Why the print $0, does that print it all?

Comment: *does not work* is still meaningless.